# jquery-ui-slider library perturbs my old jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-pagination

I have a tabbed content in my website. based on the HTML below:

```
<ul class="tabContainer">
</ul>

<div id="tabContent">
     <div id="contentHolder">
        <!-- The AJAX fetched content goes here -->
     </div>
   <div id="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

The function that manages the content of this HTML (generating tabs, executing AJAX that fetches the php pages and return the result in the tab holder):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var Tabs = {
        '1' : 'page1.php?p='+var,
        '2' : 'page2.php?p='+var,
        '3' : 'page3.php?p='+var,

    }
    var colors = ['blue','blue','blue'];

     var topLineColor = {
        blue:'lightblue',
        blue:'lightblue',
        blue:'lightblue',}

    var z=0;
    $.each(Tabs,function(i,j){

        var tmp = $('<li><a href="" class="tab '+colors[(z++%4)]+'">'+i+' <span class="left" /><span class="right" /></a></li>');


        tmp.find('a').data('page',j);


        $('ul.tabContainer').append(tmp);
    })


    var the_tabs = $('.tab');

    the_tabs.click(function(e){

        var element = $(this);

        if(element.find('#overLine').length) return false;

        var bg = element.attr('class').replace('tab ','');

        $('#overLine').remove();

        $('<div>',{
            id:'overLine',
            css:{
                display:'none',
                width:element.outerWidth()-2,
                background:topLineColor[bg] || 'white'
            }}).appendTo(element).fadeIn('slow');


        if(!element.data('cache'))
        {   

            $.get(element.data('page'),function(msg){
                $('#contentHolder').html(msg);
                element.data('cache',msg);
            });
        }
        else {
        $('#contentHolder').html(element.data('cache'));

        }
        e.preventDefault();

    })

    the_tabs.eq(2).click();

});
```

As you can see, on click on a tab, an overline appears on the top of the tab with a width equal to its width.

**Problem:**
The div with id=pagination will contain `jPaginator`, which is a code using `jquery-ui-slider`. jPaginator role is to paginate, to show a slider and to show pages numbers of content that we have put in div#contentHolder. The problem is that when  I include the library of jquery-ui-slider, the overline of tabs doesnt work correcly. when I remove the library script tag from the header, the overline width is ok, and also the way it switches between the tabs on click is ok.

I think jquery-ui-slider is containing functions that perturbs my function `tab()` !! Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.net to show the issue?

Comment: I never used  jsfiddle.net, but I think this is the opportunity, just please give me some time and I will be back here to give it. thank you  for your feedback to this matter.

Comment: Ohh,after half day of searching, I think I just should write a post on SO to find the solution in 5 minutes.  I give the solution as answer. thank you mplungjan for your time and for suggesting jsfiddle, i will learn how to use it.

Comment: Great. The problem with posts without a fiddle is that we will have to a) guess what plugin you have used and what version (and what version of jQuery) and b) eyeball code which may immediately give the reason in the console (hit F12 on  a windoes box to see it)

Comment: Totally agreeing. :-). Next js issue, jsfiddle attached. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the solution by putting `false` as parameter of outerWidth function.

```
width:element.outerWidth(false)-2,
```

It is a temporary solution since the real advice in my situation is to keep the versions of jquery and jquery-ui-slider synchronized and always up-to-date.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I see a disturbing wrapping of document.ready in `function tab(var)
{... }` You likely need to remove that

Comment: Thank you mplungjan for your usual collaboration. If I understand you well, I should remove the  document.ready from inside the function and then call the function after on document.ready? this is it?

Comment: I understand now. thank you very much. It is working and edited in the post.